# Necessary and sufficient condition for $2$-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph.

Using following definition of $2$-connectivity: Let $G$ be a graph with at least three vertices. If for every $v\in V$, the graph $G-v$ is connected, then $G$ is said to be $2$-connected.

> $G$ is $2$-connected if and only if for every $u,v\in V$, $G$ contains a cycle that contains $u,v$.

For the reverse, let $u\in V$ to be deleted. Let $v_1,v_2\in V\setminus\{u\}$.  (This selection is possible by definition ). By assumption, there exists cycle containing $v_1,v_2$ on $G$. Whether or not the cycle contains $u$, on the graph  $G-u$, there exists a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$, hence $G-u$ is connected, therefore, by definition, $G$ is $2$-connected.

---

For forward implication, we note that for every $v\in V$, $\deg (v)\geq 2$. If we assume for a contradiction, there exists $v\in V$ with $\deg (v) < 2$, then due to connectivity $\deg (v) =1$. However, $G-v'$, where $v'$ is The neighbor of $v$,  is no longer connected, therefore $G$ is not $2$-connected, a contradiction.

$\ldots $

Comment: You will have to ***use*** the assumption that $G$ is $2$-connected in your proof. The fact that the graph is connected and every vertex has degree at least $2$ is not enough to guarantee that every pair of vertices lies on a cycle.

Comment: Hint: Why don't you start by proving something easier: in a $2$-connected graph, for each vertex $u,$ there is a cycle containing $u.$ Or do you already know that?

Comment: @bof I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $G = (V,E)$ and $G$ be $2$-connected.  Let $u,v\in V$, then there exists a cycle on $G$ that contains $u,v$.

Proof by induction on $\rho (u,v)\in\mathbb{N}$, $(V,\rho )$ is a metric space.
For $\rho (u,v)=1$, $\{u,v\}=e\in E(G)$. By $2$-connectivity of $G$ the graph $G-e$ is also connected, for otherwise, $G-u$ or $G-v$ (or both) would be disconnected. By connectivity of $G-e$, a path exists from $u$ to $v$, thus on the graph $G$ exists a cycle containing $u,v$.

Next, assume for all $u,v\in V$ with $\rho (u,v)<n,\quad n\geq 2$, there exists a cycle containing these two vertices.
Now, let $\rho (u,v)=n$. Let $P$ be a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ with
$$P = (u = v_0, e_1,v_1,e_2,\ldots ,v_{n-1},e_n, v= v_n) $$
We have $\rho (u, v_{n-1})=n-1$, therefore by hypothesis, a cycle containing $u,v_{n-1}$ exists on the graph $G$, which is obviously made up by two internally vertex disjoint paths from $u$ to $v_{n-1}$, call them $P_1$ and $P_2$.
By $2$-connectivity, the graph $G-v_{n-1}$ is connected and therefore contains a path $P'$ from $u$ to $v$. Observe the last vertex on $P'$ that is in either $P_1$ or $P_2$, call it $t$.
Assume, without loss of generality,  $t$ is in $P_1$. A cycle containing $u,v$ is made up by $P_2$, the part of $P_1$ between $u$ and $t$ and the part of $P'$ between $t$ and $v$.